# How do I set matplotlib's DPI for every cell in Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When I try to set the DPI for Matplotlib plots in Jupyter, it appears to be reset in every cell:

[image]

The code:

```
# In[1]:

get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
from matplotlib import pyplot
print(pyplot.rcParams['figure.dpi'])
pyplot.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 150
print(pyplot.rcParams['figure.dpi'])

# In[2]:

print(pyplot.rcParams['figure.dpi'])
```

How do I set a consistent DPI for plots throughout the entire notebook?

This is using Jupyter 1.0.0, Matplotlib 3.0.1, Python 3.6 on Windows 10.

Comment: This issue is of interest for me as well. I haven't been able to find what is the default setting for `figure.dpi`, but reading this question I think it is 72 DPI, is that correct?

Comment: @FabioCapezzuoli I think it's usually more like 90-100, but depends on OS and other system factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug[*] in IPython. To work around that use the first cell of your notebook to set the backend. Manipulate the rcParams in subsequent cells.

[image]

---

[*] See:

- **[ipython/ipython#11098](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11098)**
- [matplotlib/matplotlib#11693](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11693)
- [matplotlib/matplotlib#11393](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11393)
- [matplotlib/matplotlib#11815](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/11815)
- [jupyter/notebook#3385](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/3385)

Let me quote here [a comment](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11098#issuecomment-381717099) by @takluyver:

> There's a bit of setup that happens just after the cell where %matplotlib inline is called, I think. So if you set things in that cell, they can be overridden by IPython's setup. After that, things you change should (I hope) be kept between cells.

Comment: Ah wonderful! I am often switching between different displays and environments, so this is much better than passing (even a global) DPI to every plotting function.